# Angular 4 Component variable of type Item initialized in subscribe response does not have methods defined in the Item class

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an Angular project for a new internal application. While I have some experience in AngularJS I am a near complete novice when it comes to Angular 2+. An issue I've run into that I can't make sense of involves the setting of some component class variables inside of a subscribe callback in the ngOnInit block. I will be a bit abstract with my details but I hope it provides enough context to convey the issue.

I have an item type defined as such:

```
export class Item {
    name: String;
    checked: boolean = false;

    // this is a simplification of the actual type and method, I'm aware this seems unnecessary
    toggle(set: boolean = false): void {
        this.checked = !this.checked || set;
    }
}
```

In my component I a declared array of items using a subscribe callback to a restful service.

```
import ...
@Component({
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './item.component.less',
  providers: [ ItemService ]
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];
  allChecked: boolean = false;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.items = items;
      }
    );
  }

  checkAll(): void {
    this.allChecked = !this.allChecked;

    for(let item of this.items) {
      item.toggle(allChecked);
    }
  }
```

In the html (as well as in the "checkAll()" function of the component above) I reference the method defined on the item type like so:

```
<input ... (change)="checkAll()" />
...
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <td>
    <input ... (change)="item[i].toggle()" />
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

I previously had the array of items being mocked inside the component ngOnInit block. When this was the case these method calls executed fine. It is only after replacing the mock data with the actual restful service call that I am having issues reaching the toggle() method. I receive an error stating that the method I'm attempting to call on my item type is undefined.

I understand that scoping is a bit wonky in javascript/typescript but since I'm using the syntactic sugar arrow format for the subscribe callback the "this" should reference the correct context, yes? Additionally, since I was at a loss I also tried using the `that = this;` outside the service call and then referencing "that" inside the callback to make sure I was setting the items property on the outer class context. Either way, it seems like as soon as I exit the context of the subscribe callback any notion of items comes back as undefined. Why is this? Am I missing some key point of Angular 2+?

Edit: I realize I was a bit too deep in the hole and was mistaking my IDEs lack of proper mapping (showing component data as undefined when debugging even if it wasn't) when in reality the data was there as a json without any method definitions. I've added more code to this post and altered the text/title to reflect this.

Comment: Can you add the HTML template please?

Comment: I think you are confused by the wrong things. Yes, the arrow function keeps "this" bound to the component. I suppose it could be related to the (completely absent in the example) code related to the service call. You write about a function called and the error is related to that call. In order to help you, that kind of information is needed. Better yet, a minimal reproducible example would be ideal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 models httpClient type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499324/angular-5-models-httpclient-type-casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a JSON response from your service call, not instances of your 
`Item` class. As plain data objects, they do not have `ItemImpl`'s method definitions. So you need to map each object to a class instance.

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

class ItemImpl implements Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(item: Item) {
    this.id = item.id;
    this.name = item.name;
  }

  someMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then map the result from the HTTP call:

```
return this.http.get<Item[]>(this.myItemsUrl)
  .pipe(
    map(items => items.map(i => new ItemImpl(i)))
  );
```

In my opinion, it would be better style to put the logic (`someMethod()`) into a service instead of the `Item` data class.